# How wil the parameters of a bi-variate normal distribution change if I rotate the x-y panel?

Tags: probability, geometry, transformation

For a bi-variate normal distribution:

[image]

If `rho = 0`, then the plot in x-y panel would look like:
[image]

I'm wonder, if I rotate the `x-y panel` a certain degree, into `u-v panel`, like this:

[image]

Then, what woudl the parameters of the bi-variate normal distributions in the new `u-v panel` be? i.e the `sigma1, sigma2, rho ...`

My thinking:

1. The `mean value` of the new bi-var Normal distribution would be easy to obtain, it's maybe something like 
   [image]
2. The main problem is the `std`, i.e. `sigma1, sigma2, rho`(or the `covariance matrix`). I don't know how they would change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the rotation matrix by $A$ and the covariance matrix by $R$. Further define a new random vector $w=Ax$ so:

1. Mean: $E[w] = E[Ax] = AE[x]$. Same result you got.

   2. Covariance matrix: $Cov[w]=Cov[Ax] = ACov[x]A^t=ARA^t$

In your case A is the rotation matrix.

Comment: For other help-seeker, you if do not know the covariance matrix property like me, you can find it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix